INET Framework in OMNeT++ 6.1 displays yellow exclamation mark after installation via IDE
I am using OMNeT++ 6.1, and after installing the INET4.5 through the IDE, I am encountering an issue where a yellow exclamation mark is displayed next to the INET framework in the project tree. This issue persists even after I’ve tried much time install from another ways here's the image.
System Information:
OMNeT++ version: 6.1
INET version: 4.5.4
Operating System: Windows
oppbuildspec (inet-4.5.4)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<buildspec version="4.0">
    <dir path="." type="custom"/>
    <dir makemake-options="--make-so --deep -o INET -O out -pINET --meta:export-include-path --meta:export-library --meta:use-exported-libs --meta:feature-cflags --meta:feature-ldflags" path="src" type="makemake"/>
</buildspec>


I tried installing the INET framework via the OMNeT++ 6.1 IDE. After installation, I cleaned and rebuilt the project and restarted the IDE, expecting the yellow exclamation mark to disappear. However, despite these attempts, the yellow exclamation mark remains next to the INET framework in the project tree, indicating an issue.
